# Lightswitch Multiple filtered tabs

Tags: lightswitch-2012

Im using lightswitch and is it possible to represent data with this kind of layout?

The files im trying to show in the list are filtered into `Types` which are `QSS`, `Installers` and `Updaters`.

I managed to put some filtering query but I dont know what to do next..
  [image]

Answer (score 0):

Make a query from the table and `Add Data Item` on the screen the queries I've made then drag it into the designer. Make sure that the filter condition is based on the choice list that you've made.